# how can I use fill(int[] a, int from_Index, int to_Index, int val) for matrix in Java?

Tags: java, fill

I want to write a program for calculating the area covered on the screen by different windows. I have the number of windows and x1,y1,x2, y2 of each windows as input. I want to use fill function in java. I want to created a matrix the size of the desktop, full of zeroes. For every window, I want to take the width of the window and input that into the matrix, for as many rows as the window height and do this for all windows, and then summarised the resulting matrix by counting the ones, giving me the area covered on the screen, without having to deal with overlapping windows.
but I don't know how could I use fill for matrix.

Comment: You want to fill an array with zeroes? Is that it? Or a two-dimensional array?

Comment: two dimensional array. I want to fill some elements of the matrix by 1. the elements that are in each windows (x1, y1, x2, y2)

Comment: Then the method signature in your title doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a 2-dim array like `matrix[WIDTH][HEIGHT]`.
You can use the `Arrays.fill()` method to fill a whole column with a single call. However, you still need to iterate over the columns.

I created a small program to illustrate. Hope it helps:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestArray
{
  public static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 100;
  public static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 100;

  class WindowCoords
  {
    public int top;
    public int left;
    public int bottom;
    public int right;

    public WindowCoords(int top,
                        int left,
                        int bottom,
                        int right)
    {
      this.top = top;
      this.left = left;
      this.bottom = bottom;
      this.right = right;
    }
  } // class WindowCoords

  public List<WindowCoords> getWindows()
  {
    List<WindowCoords> result;
    result = new ArrayList<WindowCoords>();
    result.add(new WindowCoords(4, 67, 23, 89));
    result.add(new WindowCoords(18, 12, 65, 30));
    result.add(new WindowCoords(45, 3, 95, 15));
    result.add(new WindowCoords(67, 40, 93, 59));
    return (result);
  }

  public void run()
  {
    // Initialize matrix
    // Setting its contents to 0 not strictly necessary though I prefer to do so
    int[][] matrix;
    int     column;
    matrix = new int[SCREEN_WIDTH][SCREEN_HEIGHT];
    //for (column = 0; column < SCREEN_WIDTH; column++)
    //  Arrays.fill(matrix[column], 0);

    // Get windows
    List<WindowCoords> windows;
    windows = getWindows();

    // Fill covered screen
    Iterator<WindowCoords> it;
    WindowCoords           window;
    it = windows.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
      window = it.next();
      for (column = window.left; column <= window.right; column++)
        Arrays.fill(matrix[column], window.top, window.bottom, 1);
    }

    // Show result
    int row;
    for (row = 0; row < SCREEN_HEIGHT; row++)
    {
      for (column = 0; column < SCREEN_WIDTH; column++)
        System.out.print(matrix[column][row]);
      System.out.println();
    }

  } // run

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    TestArray test;
    test = new TestArray();
    test.run();
  }

} // class TestArray
```

Comment: There's no need to fill the matrix with zeroes. `int[][] matrix = new int[10][10];` will give you a 10x10 matrix that has all values set to the default, i.e. `0` for `int`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: You're right. Maybe I'm just a fundamentalist. I updated the answer.

Comment: Don't think you're a fundamentalist. Definitely old-school though, looking at your code formatting, variable pre-declarations and use of iterators :)

Comment: I know, I'm getting old :-)

Comment: Thank you @Robert Kock for your very helpful response.

Comment: But I have still problem. when I have one window (0 0 2 2 ) with Screen size of (5 5), we have [1 1 0 0 0, 1 1 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0 0]. if I add one more window ( 1 1 3 3) it should be [1 1 0 0 0, 1 1 1 0 0, 0 1 1 0 0, 0 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0 0]. the sum of ones should be 7. but now it is 9 . [ 1 1 1 0 0, 1 1 1 0 0, 1 1 1 0 0, 0 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0 0]

Comment: @Masi: Your window (0,0,2,2) is that meant to be (top, left, width, height) or (top, left, bottom, right)? It seems to be the first one. In that case, your 2nd window has width 3 and start on the 2nd row. The 2nd row should therefore be [1,1,0,0,0] for the 1st window and [0,1,1,1,0] for the 2nd window. Together that makes [1,1,1,1,0]. Try to draw it out.

Comment: my window is (top, left, bottom, right). The 2nd row should be [1,1,0,0,0] for the 1st window and [0,1,1,0,0] for the 2nd window. but sum of them is [1, 1, 1,0, 0]. problem related for first row and third row. in fist row: first window [1 1 0 0 0], second window : [0 0 0 0 0]. sum said be [1 1 0 0 0]. but it show me [1 1 1 0 0 ]

Comment: @Masi: Maybe I'm missing something but your windows (0,0,2,2) and (1,1,3,3) both have a width and height of 3. So the 2nd row should be [1,1,1,0,0] for the 1st window and [0,1,1,1,0] for the 2nd window. Could you please post your code.

Comment: (0,0,2,2) and (1,1,3,3) are coordinate points on the x and y axis. so area of each is 4. (2-0)*(2-0)=4 and (3-1)*(3-1)=4. but they have overlap. by deleting the overlap, we have 7 as our covered area

Comment: @Robert , I add my code below my question. the format of input is n(number of windows), then x1,y1, x2, y2 for each window. output should be covered area. I did not sum ones in my code yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple nested loop will do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = new int[10][10];
    fill(matrix, 2, 2, 4, 4);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
}

private static void fill(int[][] matrix, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    for (int y = y1; y <= y2; y++) {
        for (int x = x1; x <= x2; x++) {
            matrix[y][x] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```